# React-Select, DefaultValue Fails to Disable Checkboxes in Dropdown

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, react-hooks, react-select

I'm currently working on implementing a multi-select dropdown feature using React-Select, and for the most part, it's working smoothly. However, I've run into a snag where the checkboxes don't disable upon the page loading.

Our requirement is that users shouldn't be able to select more than three values. While this restriction kicks in properly on the `onChange` event with the help of `isOptionDisabled`, it doesn't seem to apply when the page initially loads.

The console window displays the correct values for `isDisabled` and `isSelected`, as seen in the screenshot. However, these values are not reflected accurately in the user interface.

**Not working during `page load`**
[image]

**Working during `onChange`**
[image]

Below is my code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select, { components } from "react-select";
import { InputCheckBox } from "./InputCheckBox";

export default function MultiSelectDropdown({ actions, onSelect, savedActions }) {
    const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);

    const mapActionsToOptions = (actions, savedActions) => {
        if (!savedActions) {
            return actions.map(({ id, accion }) => ({
                value: id,
                label: accion,
                isSelected: false,
                isDisabled: false
            }));
        }

        const savedActionsArray = savedActions.split(',').map(Number);

        const mappedOptions = actions.map(({ id, accion }) => {
            const isSelected = savedActionsArray.includes(id);
            const isDisabled = savedActionsArray.length >= 3 && !isSelected;
            
           // console.log(`Option ${id}: isSelected - ${isSelected}, isDisabled - ${isDisabled}`);
        
            return {
                value: id,
                label: accion,
                isSelected: isSelected,
                isDisabled: isDisabled
            };
        });
        console.log(mappedOptions)
        
        return mappedOptions;
        
    };
    

    const handleChange = (selectedOptions) => {
        setSelectedOptions(selectedOptions);
        const selectedValues = selectedOptions.map((option) => option.value);
        onSelect(selectedValues);
    };

    
    const isOptionDisabled = (option) => {
        return !selectedOptions.some(selected => selected.value === option.value) && selectedOptions.length >= 3;
      };

    // Function to define custom styles
    const customStyles = {
        control: (base) => ({
            ...base,
            width: '225px',
            height: '25px'
        })
    };
    
    const InputOption = (props) => <InputCheckBox {...props} />;

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Select
                defaultValue={mapActionsToOptions(actions, savedActions).filter(option => option.isSelected)}
                isMulti
                closeMenuOnSelect={false}
                hideSelectedOptions={false}
                isSearchable={false}
                controlShouldRenderValue={false}
                placeholder="Seleccionar acciones"
                onChange={handleChange}
                options={mapActionsToOptions(actions, savedActions)}
                isOptionDisabled={isOptionDisabled}
                components={{ Option: InputOption}}
                styles={customStyles}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select, { components } from "react-select";

export const InputCheckBox = ({
  getStyles,
  isDisabled,
  isFocused,
  isSelected,
  children,
  innerProps,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const onMouseDown = () => setIsActive(true);
  const onMouseUp = () => setIsActive(false);
  const onMouseLeave = () => setIsActive(false);

  // styles
  let bg = "transparent";
  if (isFocused) bg = "#eee";
  if (isActive) bg = "#B2D4FF";

  const style = {
      alignItems: "center",
      backgroundColor: bg,
      color: "inherit",
      display: "flex "
  };

  // prop assignment
  const props = {
      ...innerProps,
      onMouseDown,
      onMouseUp,
      onMouseLeave,
      style
  };

  return (
      <components.Option
          {...rest}
          isFocused={isFocused}
          getStyles={getStyles}
          innerProps={props}
      >
          <input type="checkbox" checked={isSelected} disabled={isDisabled} onChange={() =>{}}/>&nbsp;
          {children}
      </components.Option>
  );
};
```

Furthermore, `isDisabled` and `isSelected` values are dynamically calculated based on the data from an API, which only returns the value(`id`) and label(`accion`).